# Performance degradation after upgrading to Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table to access Azure table storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net

We upgraded to the next version of SDK to access our Azure Table storage.

We observed performance degradation of our application after that. We even created test applications with identical usage pattern to isolate it, and still see this performance hit.

We are using .NET Framework code, reading data from Azure table.

Old client: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage - 9.3.2

New client: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table - 1.0.6

Here is one of the sample tests we tried to run:

```
public async Task ComparisionTest1()
{
    var partitionKey = CompanyId.ToString();

    {
        // Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table
        var storageAccount = Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
        var tableClient = Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.CloudStorageAccountExtensions.CreateCloudTableClient(storageAccount);
        var tableRef = tableClient.GetTableReference("UserStatuses");
        var query = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableEntity>()
                            .Where(Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", "eq", partitionKey));
        var result = new List<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableEntity>(20000);

        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var tableQuerySegment = await tableRef.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);
        result.AddRange(tableQuerySegment.Results);
        while (tableQuerySegment.ContinuationToken != null)
        {
            tableQuerySegment = await tableRef.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, tableQuerySegment.ContinuationToken);
            result.AddRange(tableQuerySegment.Results);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Trace.WriteLine($"Cosmos table client. Elapsed: {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
    }

    {
        // Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
        var storageAccount = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var tableRef = tableClient.GetTableReference("UserStatuses");
        var query = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity>()
                            .Where(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", "eq", partitionKey));
        var result = new List<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity>(20000);

        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var tableQuerySegment = await tableRef.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);
        result.AddRange(tableQuerySegment.Results);
        while (tableQuerySegment.ContinuationToken != null)
        {
            tableQuerySegment = await tableRef.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, tableQuerySegment.ContinuationToken);
            result.AddRange(tableQuerySegment.Results);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Trace.WriteLine($"Old table client. Elapsed: {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
    }
}
```

Anyone observed it, any thoughts about it?

Comment: `We observed performance degradation of our application after that. We even created test applications with identical usage pattern to isolate it, and still see this performance hit.` - Please edit your question and include more details like for which operations you're seeing performance problems etc.

Comment: Updated: Included code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance issue will be resolved in Table SDK 1.0.7 as verified with large entity.
On 1.0.6 the workaround is to disable Table sdk trace by adding diagnostics section in app.config if it's a .NET framework app. It will still be slower than Storage sdk, but much better than without the workaround depending on the usage.

Comment: source name="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table"
switchName="ClientSwitch"
switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch"
In switches seciontion, add name="ClientSwitch" value="Off"

Answer (score 1):

I think your data are stored in the legacy Storage Table. Just in case, if this is CosmosDB Table backed, you may get better performance if you set TableClientConfiguration.UseRestExecutorForCosmosEndpoint to True.

If it's the legacy Storage Table store, CosmosDB Table sdk 1.0.6 is about 15% slower than Storage Table sdk 9.3.3. In addition, it has an extra second overhead upon the first CRUD operation. Higher query duration has been resolved in 1.0.7, which is on-par with Storage SDK. The initialization second is still required why using CosmosDB Table sdk 1.0.7, which should be acceptable.

We are planning to release 1.0.7 during the week of 4/13.

Comment: Yes, we are on classic storage, we will repeat our tests on v2 storage.
However, the degradation is  not 15%, these are the numbers for our sample:
Old client  - 0:34
New client - 1:37
Updated: results are when test ran in Azure VM

Comment: My perf benchmark was based on 5000 ~1kb entities, and below are the output using Table SDK 1.0.6:
1 Page of 1000 entities took 00:00:00.5731967
1 Page of 1000 entities took 00:00:01.0005410
1 Page of 1000 entities took 00:00:00.6324008
1 Page of 1000 entities took 00:00:00.6053916
1 Page of 1000 entities took 00:00:00.5835644
CosmosDB table client. Total Elapsed: 00:00:03.3968653

Comment: It seems you're experiencing much longer duration of 1 minute and half. Can you please share more details so I can get a local repro? (sample entity, total rows of the same partition key)

Comment: send me an email to paulchen@microsoft.com, so we can set up a meeting. Once resolved, we can update this thread.

Comment: Thank you for response, I will email.

Comment: @PaulChen I am experiencing similar issues with performance degradation when using an empty table query to retrieve all entities in a table. I have set up a benchmark test using a cosmos db table account and a storage account. Both tables have the same data set of roughly 200k entities. When using the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage lib on the storage account i'm seeing an average execution time around ~2 minutes. When using the CosmosDB Table SDK 1.0.7 on the cosmos table im seeing ~3 hours with the Cosmos Executor and ~3 minutes with the rest executor. Any help would be much appreciated.